# Run a file through Porter Stemmer

Tags: python, nltk, porter-stemmer

I am new to python and practicing with examples from book.
I can stem one word:

```
>>> from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
>>> stemmer=PorterStemmer()
>>> stemmer.stem('programming')
'program'
```

But I cannot for example run the first 50 words of a text file through the Porter stemmer.

EDIT: Is there any way other than split(). split() sometimes gives wrong result.

Comment: `for word in open('/path/to/file').read().split()[:50]: print(stemmer.stem(word))`

Comment: *note that file.read().split() assumes tokenization ;P

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading a file that has one token per line, you should strip the token of the new line before running the stemmer.

```
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer

stemmer = PorterStemmer()

with open('tokens.txt', 'r') as fp:
    tokens = fp.readlines()

for t in tokens:
    s = stemmer.stem(t.strip())
    print(s)
```

Answer (score -1):

What about

```
wholefile = open("text.txt", "r").read()
words = wholefile.split()
stems = [ stemmer.stem(word) for word in words]
```

EDIT: Actually, the commenting poster gives you the same, but more comprehensively. Use his solution.

EDIT2: thanks, falsetru :)

Comment: @user2064809: No. falsetru's code is correct and complete on its own, and I don't plan to plagiarize it. Falsetru decided to post it in a comment, and I respect that choice. Iff falsetru's intent was to post his code in an answer, he/she could do that him/herself without further work.

Comment: it doesn't stem correctly. for example '_Melody_' should converted to 'Melodi'. but it remains 'Melody'. And sometimes it doesn't remove the 's' from end of words. is this problem because of split()?!